# Android Studio with Chaquopy: Tesseract Not Installed or Not in PATH

Tags: android, tesseract, python-tesseract, chaquopy

I'm trying to create an OCR android app. I already have a functioning script in python and I'm trying to Implement it with chaquopy. I did the necessary config in `build.gradle`.

```
python{
    version "3.8"
    buildPython "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe"
    pip {
        // A requirement specifier, with or without a version number:
        install "packaging"
        install "pillow"
        install "pytesseract"}

}
```

This is the script inside the src/main/Python/ocr.py

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image as PIL_image

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd =\
                                      r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
tessdata_dir_config = r'--tessdata-dir "C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\teepee\app\src\main\python\tessdata"'


def bitmaptoString(bitmap):
    res= pytesseract.image_to_string(bitmap, lang='eng', config=tessdata_dir_config)
    return res
def test():
    return "chaquopy in the works"
```

When invoking this:

```
python = Python.getInstance();
PyObject pobj = python.getModule("ocr");
String ouText=pobj.callAttr("bitmaptoString",bitmap.toString()).toString();
Log.e("_______________","TESSER:");
Log.e("OUTPUT_OF_PYFUNC",ouText);
```

It says that tesseract is not found:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/10101 flg=0x1 launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.teepee/com.example.teepee.mainActivity}: com.chaquo.python.PyException: TesseractNotFoundError: C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.
```

I also tried building a static tesseract with vcpkg and adding the path to the executable but the same problem happens.

I really need your help.

Comment: So you expect that MS Windows x86 executable (tesseract.exe) will run on Android (arm linux)???

Comment: I'm still a beginner but I thought if the python script is functional. Chaquopy will take care of building a compatible binary.

Comment: As far as I see on Chaquopy web, it will handle python code. So you have to build tesseract (which is not python script) for android by yourself.

Comment: The above comments are correct: Chaquopy does not automatically build any binary executables or libraries. Instead, we provide a separate build tool which can produce wheel files which you then install into your app. See [here](https://github.com/chaquo/build-wheel) for the tool, or [here](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/220) for updates on tesseract specifically.